# Why is this java calculator giving me this answer?

Tags: java, calculator

I made myself a calculator:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Jcal_00_b2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int a;
    a = 0;
    int b;
    b = 0;
    int res = 0;
    String c;
    String men;
    BufferedReader ra = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader rb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader rc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    BufferedReader rmen = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    System.out.println("Jcal 0.0 b2.....type start to add type help for help and credits.");
    men= rmen.readLine();
    if(men.equals("")){
        System.out.println("Give input please");
        men= rmen.readLine();
    }else if(men.equals("start")){
    System.out.println("Type first number");
    a=(int) ra.read();
     System.out.println("Type Second number");
     b=(int) rb.read();
      System.out.println("Type operation (*,/,+,-)");
      c=rc.readLine();
      if(c.equals("+")){
          res=a+b;
      }else if(c.equals("-")){
        res=a-b;  
      }else if(c.equals("*")){
          res=a*b;
      }else if(c.equals("-")){
        res=a/b;   
      } 
      System.out.println("result:" +res);
      System.out.println("You gave input: \n 1st no.="+a+"\n 2nd no.="+b );

}else if(men.equals("help")){
    System.out.print("first type start to start the calc.\n then input first number, input second number then input the operator. \n the operator symbols are as follows:\n + for addition \n - for subtraction \n * for multiplication \n / for division  ");

}


}



}
```

When I run it it displays the following output:

> Jcal, a calculator .....type start to add type help for help and credits.
>
> start
>
> Type first number
>
> 1
>
> Type Second number
>
> 1
>
> Type operation (*,/,+,-)
>
> *
>
> result:2401
>
> You gave input:
>
> 1st no.=49
>
> 2nd no.=49

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the `read` method of `BufferedReader` returns the ASCII value of a single character from the `BufferedReader`.  The ASCII value of the single digit `'1'` is `49`.

You might want to consider using a `Scanner` instead of a `BufferedReader`, and using the `nextInt()` method instead.  Then you won't have this problem.

Additionally, you only need one `Scanner` object, not one per value that you wish to read.

One more thing to be careful of - you can call `nextLine()` on a `Scanner` object, but if you have just called `nextInt()`, it's possible that there'll be an extra newline character before the line with the operator on.  You may need to call `nextLine()` twice.  That is to say, the `Scanner` may contain something like `"1 newline 1 newline * newline"` - in which case you'll need to call `nextInt()` (to get the first 1), `nextInt()` (to get the second 1), `nextLine()` (to get the second newline) then `nextLine()` again to get the `*` character.